# Is it possible to make OData's spatial queries over Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, entity-framework-6

I am trying to allow queries over my Entity Framework's entities (OData). 
Some of my entities are of DBGeography and i would like to make queries over them. 
I fail on such queries:

> api/towns?$filter=geo.distance(Location,Point (0.0 0.0)) lt 100

with

> "')' or ',' expected at position 28 in 'geo.distance(Location,Point (0.0 0.0)) lt 100'."

Comment: Have you figured it out?!

Answer (score 1):

According to ODATA.org ([link](http://www.odata.org/geospatial-data-support-in-odata/)) ([link](http://www.odata.org/geospatial-properties/)) it should be

```
http://domain.com/api/controller?
$filter=geo.distance(Location, geography'Point(-71.798 45.144)') lt 10000
```

but web api throws this exception:

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Unknown function 'geo.distance'.",
"ExceptionType": "System.NotImplementedException",
```

I guess it is not supported at this time, hopefully it will be soon. There is a discussion about it on [ASP.NET's Codeplex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/496037), but no answers.

Comment: Oh, well all in one place now! I've ditched ODATA for now.. I hope Microsoft makes this work soon!